# Как синхронизировать обращение к глобальной статической переменной из 2 потоков

Tags: java

Нужно создать Класс, содержащий статическую переменную с модификатором public. Затем стартовать из main 2 разных потока, которые будут в произвольном порядке изменять эту глобальную переменную пока не завершатся.
Я зделал так:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

public synchronized void Change(int a)
{
    if (a % 2 == 0) MainClass.variable +=2; 
    else MainClass.variable -=2;   
}

public void run() 
{ 
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
   Change(i);
  System.out.println("V = "+MainClass.variable+"\t i = "+i+"\t Thread Name "+this.getName());
}
}
}
```

и

```
public class MainClass {

public static volatile int variable = 0;

synchronized protected void CreateThread()
{
 Thread task = new MyThread(); 
 task.start();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
MainClass mc=new MainClass();
mc.CreateThread();
mc.CreateThread();
}
}
```

Но работает оно неправильно. Нужно чтобы все изменения переменной были видны на экране, то есть если один из потоков увелечил или уменьшил MainClass.variable, он должен вывести это на экран до того как управление перейдет другому потоку. Иначе получается полная ерунда, на консоль выводится совершенно непредсказуемый значения MainClass.variable. Что я сделал неправильно?

Answer (score 4):

Надо сделать `MainClass.variable` приватным и сделать к нему доступ через защищенные (`synchronized`) геттеры и сеттеры. Иначе, все так и будет сыпаться.

Это идеологически неправильно пытаться синхронизировать доступ к глобальной публичной переменной. Все равно найдется какая-нибудь сволочь, которая будет напрямую стучаться к переменной и потом орать что *нифиганеработает!*

**Update** Вчитавшись еще раз в пост автора, я отметил ранее пропущенное мною:

> он должен вывести это на экран до того
> как управление перейдет другому потоку

ИМХО это всего лишь означает, что надо синхронизировать вывод данных совместно с сеттером, тогда будет правильно отображаться и меняться.

Comment: Согласен с @Next_Alex объявление геттера `synchronized` это перебор

Comment: Совет, как считается надо программировать, это конечно хорошо, но совсем не объясняет наблюдаемый автором вывод на экран.

Answer (score 2):

Мысль работала в правильном направлении, но не до конца.
Смысл в том что любое обращение к переменной должно быть потокобезопасным, а у тебя значение переменной изменяется в защищенном методе, а потом ты это значение получаешь прямым обращением к переменной, хотя в этот момент второй поток его как раз изменяет.

Самый простой способ - метод Change должен возвращать новое значение переменной либо вывод значения должен происходить внутри метода Change.

Comment: Синхронизация через защищенные сеттеры это, конечно, очень правильно, но защищает только от попытки одновременного изменения значения переменной. Защищать геттеры вообще не имеет смысла.

Конкретно в приведенном случае проблема заключается в том что изменение переменной производится в потокозащищенном методе, а вывод значения - уже после выхода из этого защищенного метода и снятия всех блокировок. Соответственно, в момент получения значения вполне может изменяться или уже быть изменено вторым потоком. И защищенный геттер тут не поможет.

Comment: Все что нужно - сделать так чтобы изменение и получение нового значения переменной осуществлялись в одной закрытой зоне.

Answer (score 2):

Правильней всего обозначить переменную как `volatile` И БОЛЬШЕ НЕЧЕГО.

посмотри [пример](http://invalidcodeexception.com/java-volatile-keyword-by-example/), тцт очень наглядно все показано и ты сможешь модифицировать его для себя

Comment: @Gorets она и так уже обозначена как `volatile`

Comment: я вижу, этого должно хватить, без блоков синхронизации

Comment: Я изменил код:
...
private volatile static int variable = 0; 
synchronized public static void SetVariable(int k)
{
variable=k;
}
synchronized public static int GetVariable()
{
return variable;
}
...
и
...
private synchronized void Change(int a)
{
 int k = MainClass.GetVariable();
    if (a % 2 == 0) k += 2; 
    else k -= 2;  
 System.out.println("V = "+k+"\t i = "+a+"\t Thread Name "+this.getName()); 
 MainClass.SetVariable(k);
}
Но теперь каждый поток делает копию variable, а надо чтобы если 1 поток прибавил 2, а потом заработал 2 поток, то 2 тоже прибавил и вышло 4. А выводится
2
2
0
0
2
2

Comment: То есть первый поток выводит 2, потом управление получает второй поток и выводит 02 (хотя первый поток уже увеличил значение на 2 и должно быть 4) и т. п. Еще я заметил, что сколько раз эту программу не запусти - система передает управление поочередно потокам, хотя раньше они могли в произвольном порядке выполнятся.Мне не обязательно чтобы они поочередно изменяли переменную, можно в любом порядке, но как сделать, чтобы если 1 поток прибавил двойку, то второй прибавлял 2 к уже новому значению, а не к нулю? Вроде уже переменная приватная, вывод происходит в том же методе, где и изменения.

Comment: Кстати как оформлять правильно код? Я не вижу в поле ответа кнопочки для вставки блока кода(
Цель этой работы - чтобы потоки в произвольном порядке изменяли переменную variable, но если один поток изменил, то второй поток уже изменял измененное значение (тавтология, но зато понятно). Поэтому я ее и делал паблик. Плюс сразу после изменения новое значение выводилось на экран, и не было такого, что пока оно выводится на экран какой-то поток его еще раз изменил и вывелось непонятно что. Или не успел изменить, но на экран уже вывел. Нужно так: изменили переменную, вывели, передали управление.

Answer (score 0):

Создай синхронизированный сеттер для данной переменной, например так

```
private static Integer param;
public static synchronized void setParam(Integer value){
    param=value;        
}
```